# Javascript property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function ordersUtil() {

    var obj = {

        currentPage: 1
    }

    return obj;
}


console.log(ordersUtil.currentPage);
```

**console.log(ordersUtil.currentPage); returns undefined.**

I am setting up default property within my javaScript object literal, however why cant I simply access it? I know I can do **ordersUtil.currentPage = 1 after my object** and then i will have its value. my question is how do I setup default values and access them?

Comment: `ordersUtil().currentPage` will return what you want, but `ordersCutil.currentPage` will not.

Comment: Yes, you have to call that function for anything to happen :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `undefined` because the `function` itself doesn't have that property. If you called it, the `Object` that's returned, however, would:

```
var orders = ordersUtil();

console.log(orders.currentPage);
```

The `function` could hold the property, as you found out:

> *I know I can do `ordersUtil.currentPage = 1` after my object [...]*

But, it doesn't currently.

Comment: so ordersUtil() create a instance of object?

Comment: @highwingers Not quite. The braces (`{...}`) will [create the `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), which `ordersUtil()` can then `return`. But, you just have to call `ordersUtil()` for it to do so.

Comment: I understand, but then how come after i set its value, i can access it without using ordersUtil().

Comment: @highwingers Because JavaScript's `Function`s are also objects and can be given properties of their own. Just, in your current snippet, `currentPage` simply belongs to a different object.

Comment: oh man, i feel so stupid right now, i totally forgot i have another object within my function. lol